ESAPI Throwing Exception when calling ESAPI.httpUtilities().setHeader()
I have a JSP Page that is used to Export Search-Results as a Downloadable Excel file, as a part of this process we use ESAPI to set the header when downloading the export that is called from a controller:
ArrayList rows = downloadReportUCService2.downloadReport(reportOptionsBean);
ESAPI.httpUtilities().setHeader(res, "Content-disposition", "filename=" + downloadReportUCService2.getReportFileName(reportOptionsBean));

When I hit the setHeader() call I get this error in my try-catch trace:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException HTTPUtilities class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultHTTPUtilities) CTOR threw exception.

and this information gets dumped in my console log, however this doesn't look to be directly related to the error I'm occurring.
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via file I/O.
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties as resource file via file I/O.
Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: C:\profilename\software\apache-tomcat-9.0.68-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.68\bin\ESAPI.properties
Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi\ESAPI.properties
Not found in 'user.home' (C:\Users\profilename) directory: C:\Users\profilename\esapi\ESAPI.properties
Loading ESAPI.properties via file I/O failed. Exception was: java.io.FileNotFoundException
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via the classpath.
SUCCESSFULLY LOADED ESAPI.properties via the CLASSPATH from 'esapi/' using current thread context class loader!
Attempting to load validation.properties via file I/O.
Attempting to load validation.properties as resource file via file I/O.
Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: C:\profilename\software\apache-tomcat-9.0.68-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.68\bin\validation.properties
Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi\validation.properties
Not found in 'user.home' (C:\Users\profilename) directory: C:\Users\profilename\esapi\validation.properties
Loading validation.properties via file I/O failed.
Attempting to load validation.properties via the classpath.
SUCCESSFULLY LOADED validation.properties via the CLASSPATH from '/ (root)' using current thread context class loader!

looking up this error and some other related information, I've seen a lot of mentions of missing configurations in the properties file but I referred to a few of the ESAPI.properties configuration templates I've seen online and the one used by my application looks largely unchanged. I also did validate we do have a .Logger property set in our .properties file. We have not updated past v2.0.1 so none of the changes from the reorganization from v2.2 should apply.
I can share more code-snippets, I just didn't want to drown the post in needless amounts of details if for some reason I am missing something simple.

Can you add the full stack trace of the error please. Also the information you mentioned it is dumped in the logs is just the ESAPI start up debug logs, and there were nothing wrong with it, so it is irrelevant.

The full stacktrace isn't set to print to the console, Upon hitting the export again the deep-diving through the full trace object and looking at the cause: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/spi/LoggerFactory. It looks like we're missing some Log4J dependency.

Glad that you were able to figure it out.
